# Solve Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am getting this eror while uploading a Image file using FileUpload. I am getting this error on button click event to insertion

```
  public int InsertData(ProductPhoto prdctphoto)
        {
            int ans = 0;
            SqlCommand cmd = DataConnection.GetConnection().CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "prcProductPhoto";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
           // cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PhotoID", prdctphoto.PhotoID));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PhotoName", prdctphoto.PhotoName));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ExtName", prdctphoto.ExtName));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PhotoType", prdctphoto.PhotoType));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PhotoSize", prdctphoto.PhotoSize));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProductID", prdctphoto.ProductID));
            ans = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
            cmd.Dispose();
            DataConnection.CloseConnection();
            return ans;
        }
```

i am getting the error in line

ans = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

The code of my Stored Procedure is

```
create proc prcProductPhoto
(
@PhotoName  Varchar(100),
@ExtName    Varchar(100),
@PhotoType  Varchar(100),
@PhotoSize  int,
@ProductID  Int
)
as
insert into ProductPhoto(PhotoName,ExtName,PhotoType,PhotoSize,ProductID) values (@PhotoName,@ExtName,@PhotoType,@PhotoSize,@ProductID)
```

and code on button click event is

```
protected void Insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            if (photoupload.HasFile)
            {
                ProductPhoto prdctphoto = new ProductPhoto();
                prdctphoto.PhotoName = photoupload.FileName;
                prdctphoto.PhotoSize = photoupload.PostedFile.ContentLength;
                prdctphoto.PhotoType = photoupload.PostedFile.ContentType;
                prdctphoto.ExtName = prdctphoto.PhotoName.Substring(prdctphoto.PhotoName.LastIndexOf(".") + 1);
                prdctphoto.ProductID = int.Parse(ddlproductname.SelectedValue);
                //Response.Write(data.ExtName);
                int ans = new InsertAction().InsertData(prdctphoto);
                if (ans != 0)
                {
                    string path = Server.MapPath("~/upload/") + ans.ToString() + "." + prdctphoto.ExtName;
                    photoupload.SaveAs(path);
                    Response.Write(" File is Uploaded ");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does your SP definitely return a number?

Comment: My crystall ball is in maintenance today, so can you please show the code for the stored procedure?

Comment: So you can test the value of the result, re-write the code as this: `var result=cmd.ExecuteScalar(); ans=int.Parse(result.ToString());`, this way you can put a breakpoint on the var result line so you can see the result from the query before you try to shoehorn it into an int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) will return the value of the first column from the first row of the first result-set produced by the query.

Your stored procedure doesn't return any result-set, so `ExecuteScalar` will return `null`. When you call `cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()`, you're calling a method on a `null` instance, which is why you're getting a `NullReferenceException`.

To fix the problem, you will need to change your stored procedure to return an appropriate value. It's not obvious from the query what that value should be, but assuming you have an identity column on the `ProductPhoto` table which you want to return, you could try something like:

```
create proc prcProductPhoto
(
   @PhotoName  varchar(100),
   @ExtName    varchar(100),
   @PhotoType  varchar(100),
   @PhotoSize  int,
   @ProductID  Int
)
As
   insert into ProductPhoto
   (
      PhotoName,
      ExtName,
      PhotoType,
      PhotoSize,
      ProductID
   ) 
   values 
   (
      @PhotoName,
      @ExtName,
      @PhotoType,
      @PhotoSize,
      @ProductID
   )

   select Scope_Identity()
```

Comment: thank you so so so  much sir... for helping me i am not having privilege to vote up  but whenever i will get i i will do it for u thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

I was just running into this problem earlier today. This error means that the value you are supposed to have initialized in "ans" is null. Try to debug it and make sure that it actually stores a value.